# Launching a long-running background task - from ASP.NET or a scheduled job

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-4.0, long-running-processes

I have a fairly long-running process (several minutes) that I need to run roughly once a month - but not on a fixed schedule, but after a user clicks <kbd>Go</kbd> in a ASP.NET Webforms GUI page.

Since ASP.NET really isn't designed to handle long-running background tasks, my idea was to put this into a separate console app. But how to launch that as needed?

What happens if I use `Process.Start(....)` from my ASP.NET page's code-behind? I would like to avoid  blocking the whole Web UI for 20 minutes or so... and also: even if it doesn't block my UI, what happens to my long-running task if the ASP.NET app pool recycles while it's still running?

Another idea was to have a frequently running job (runs every 2 minutes) check for some kind of a flag (e.g. existence of some database entries), and if needed, that job would then launch the long-running task.

But the same question: if I launch my 20-minute task from a job using `Process.Start()` - does that block the caller?

It seems like a bit of overkill to schedule that long running tasks five times a day since it typically is run only once a month - but at the same time, the user expects to have his results within a reasonable amount of time (less than 1 hour, if ever possible) after scheduling the process - so I cannot really just schedule it to run once at night either ...

Comment: have you tried Task Parallel Liberaries to run a task in background without blocking UI?

Comment: @ImranRizvi who cares for stopping IIS, restarting IIS (how to handle previously not completed tasks) ... I simply suggest a service with quartz.net (+ a persisted job store) as the worker + eg serviceStack as the communication between the website and the service ...

Comment: Check this nice post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Since your background task takes more than 90 sec (you say it takes 20 min), **DONT USE** `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` which is available from .NET framework 4.5.2 onwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off - for several reasons - ASP.NET is imho **not** the solution for long-running tasks/jobs/... whatsoever.

I have had this requirement a lot of times, and always solved/separated it like:

**Worker**
A service with

- [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) (for scheduling and processing, even if you don't have a specific timestamp for execution - but the overall handling in this framework is simply superb)
- a persistent job-store (to handle start/stop and completed/aborted/paused jobs)
- eg [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) as the interop between the two processes

**Website**
Simply calls some webservice-methods of the worker to enqueue/query/pause/stop/... a job. For querying jobs a call to a unified job-store might be an option (eg. db)

It might be a bit of an overkill for you though ... but this is my Swiss army knife for such scenarios.

Comment: A service? Windows Service ? How comunícate WebSite and Windows Service ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Frontend communicates with backend via a webservice (rpc, rest, ... whatsoever), which communicates with a windows service via a webservice (rpc, rest, ... whatsoever)

Answer (score 7):

Hangfire is what you are looking for. Best part is it comes with a built in dashboard.

You might have to write some logic on the top of it.

You can find it here.
http://hangfire.io/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using ***hangfire*** `step by step` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard built-in Windows Task Scheduler like you have done, but invoke it from your web application.

Configure your task in Task Scheduler. It does not need to have a scheduled trigger. From your web application, just use `Process.Start` to kick it off:

```
SchTasks.exe /Run /TN Folder\Taskname
```

I have not used `SchTasks.exe` directly, but have used the [Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler](https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler) wrapper classes.